# Unable to see layout preview in Adt

Tags: android, adt, graphical-layout-editor

Earlier i used to  see,modify layouts in my ADT itself on Graphical layout Editor tab,but now iam not able see now is there any thing to update or that feature is removed or any reason.if these is any way to get it back please let me know

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse once.

Comment: this problem iam facing it from few days,anyway i have restarted it now eventhough not able to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some workaround you can try :

**1. Change android version in your layout editor**

Try to increase or decrease android version in your layout editor. Sometimes this trick solve the problem.

**2. Create new workspace**

Create new workspace in eclipse and import your project in new workspace. Sometimes a new workspace solve this kind of issues.

Comment: thanQ so much changing(Decreasing from 4.3 to 4.2.2)Android version on layout worked for me,but won't it cause any problem later